# I am getting duplicate key error -- MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection. I do have 2 collections, user and profile.

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to make a project which should have following flow.
Registration -> Login -> Profile Creation -> The secret page
I have implemented the registration and login routes but when I am saving data for the profile page, It is showing the above error. I am able to save the data first time only. I can not able to save the data for other users also. Thank You.

```
// This is the route which i am including.

    var express                 = require('express');
    var router                     = express.Router();
    var passport                 = require('passport');
    var multer                     = require('multer');
    var mongoose                 = require('mongoose');
    var User                     = require('../models/user.model.js');
    var Profile                 = require('../models/profile.model.js');
    var path                     = require('path');

// Defining the storage path to the multer    
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination : 'uploads/',
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, file.filedname + '-' +Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    },
    fileFilter: function(file, cb){
    checkFileType(file, cb);
    }
    });

// 
    var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
    });


//The signup route to post the username and password and register in the database
    router.post('/signup', function(req, res){
    req.body.username
    req.body.password
    User.register(new User({username : req.body.username}), req.body.password, function(err, user){
    if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.render('signup.ejs');
    } 
    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function(){
    res.render('profile.ejs');
    });
    });
    });


// The login route to post the username and password and login into the portal
    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect : '/secret',
    failureRedirect : '/login'
    }), function (req, res) {

// body...
// console.log("Login Working");
    });

// The profile route to render the profile page only if logged in
    router.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    res.render('profile.ejs')
    });

// The profile route. This route is generating error        
    router.post('/profile', upload.any(), function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var profileDetails = {};
    profileDetails.path = req.files[0].path;
    profileDetails.originalname = req.files[0].originalname;
    profileDetails.name = req.body.profileName;
    profileDetails.email = req.body.profileEmail;
    Profile.create(profileDetails, function(err){
    if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    }
    res.redirect('/missing');
    });
    });

    router.get('/missing', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
// body...
    res.render('missing.ejs')
    })

//The function to check is user is logged in or not
    function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/login');
    }

    module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message? It's hard to say which key it complains about.

Comment: { MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: demo-db.profiles index: username_1 dup key: { : null }
    at Function.MongoError.create (E:\Demo\V5\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:49:10)    at toError (E:\Demo\V5\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:149:22)
    at coll.s.topology.insert (E:\Demo\V5\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\collection_ops.js:803:39)
    at E:\Demo\V5\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:531:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

Comment: You are creating document with same username..

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting is saying that there's already a username with the value of `null`. It means that there's already a user without a username, and you're trying to add another one.

The Mongo documentation states the following about these situations:

> If a document does not have a value for the indexed field in a unique index, the index will store a null value for this document. Because of the unique constraint, MongoDB will only permit one document that lacks the indexed field. If there is more than one document without a value for the indexed field or is missing the indexed field, the index build will fail with a duplicate key error.
>
> You can combine the unique constraint with the sparse index to filter
>   these null values from the unique index and avoid the error.

Either you need to validate that there's a real username when registering the user, or you need to add a [sparse index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/) to the collection. (which allows you to enter several entries with null values but will only return the ones that has proper values).